# Select a variable with an other variable

Tags: javascript

I got data from a JSON file, i can access values this way :

```
json.x.price.cur_eur
json.x.price.cur_usd
...
```

I want to now if this is possible to get the value from a variable according to an other variable directly without an if/then ?
It would be something like this :

```
curency = "eur"
myprice = json.x.price.cur_ + curency
```

I'm hopping i'm not asking a dumb question... 
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var curency = "eur";
var myprice = json.x.price[curency];

json.x.price[curency] === json.x.price.eur;  // true
```

You can access the properties of an object either by dot or by []-notation.

Another example:

```
var o = { 'my property': 100 };
// "my property" can not be accessed by dot-notation
o['my property'] === 100; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties on objects using dot notation or brackets. The latter allows you to use variables for the property name:

```
myprice = json.x.price[curency];
```